# How to generate a values using random.gauss in python for the range 0, 50

Tags: python

I am confused with the concept of random.gauss() in python, as explained gauss function takes mean and standard deviation as the parameter.

For instance if I want to generate random numbers in the range 0-50 using gauss specifically, what would be the parameters. I tried using the mean and standard deviation of the range 0-50. Unfortunately it does not fetch me the correct list.

Comment: Are you asking about statistics, or this function?

Answer (score 4):

A Gaussian distribution is infinite, so you can't generate numbers guaranteed to be between two boundaries. You can set the median to be 25 and the standard deviation to make it very unlikely that a number will fall outside 0 or 50, but of course it's a tradeoff: either the lower/higher numbers won't be anywhere close to 0/50, or there will be plenty of outliers.

In practice you could do something like:

```
random.gauss(25, 25/3)
```

and know that 99.7% of your results will be within 0 and 5 (+- 3 sigma from the mean). You can avoid going out of bounds by retrying if you get a value above 50 or below 0, but then it's not truly a Gaussian anymore. It may be what you need though, a good enough approximation depending on what you're trying to model/simulate.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. can you please explain the standard deviation further more. "25/3" , this is not the exact standard deviation. How to calculate this value when there is a different range??

Comment: This chart may be helpful. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#/media/File:Empirical_Rule.PNG See the wikipedia page for "normal distribution" for more details.

Comment: The way I "fixed" gaussian distribution to always fit within a range was to generate the number then loop round averaging it with the mean value until it fit within the range. You could do this more efficiently by shifting the mean to zero (subtract 25 in your case) and take the modulus by the range (25 again) of the value then add the mean back on again.